# Solidity - ether transfer from contract to contract issue

Tags: solidity

I have an issue to transfer the ether from a contract to another contract.
Here is the concept code.

If the address _to is a user address. The function can transfer the ether to the user.

If the address _to is a contract address. The program will stop working.

Need help. Thanks.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract ethTransferTest {
    function ethTrans(address _to) payable public {
        uint256 pay = msg.value;
        _to.transfer(pay);
    }
}
```

Comment: Share the stack trace and contract code where funds are being sent

Comment: could you show the code of the contract that is receiving the ether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually happens because there is a limitation in the amount of gas that the method transfer pass to the receiving contract. Transfer pass only 2300 gas which means that is the code in the `fallback` function of the receiving contract consumes more than 2300 gas, then the transfer will fail.

Assume these two contracts

```
contract ethTransferTest {
    function ethTrans(address _to) public {
        uint256 pay = msg.value;
        _to.transfer(pay);
    }
}


contract ethReceiverTest {
    function () payable public {
    }
}
```

This will work, but as soon as you start including methods in the `fallback` function in ethReceiverTest, you will start having problems. 2300 gas will only be enough for a few operations.

Comment: Yes. I tested the code and it is working. Thanks a lot.